# split a string according to repeating regular expression in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

In Scala I have a string of the form

```
val str = "[ab][bc][cd][dx][42]"
```

What is the most efficient way in Scala, regular expression utilizing or otherwise, to split that string into a `Seq[String]` that would be of the form:

```
("ab","bc","cd","dx","42")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
val str = "[ab][bc][cd][dx][42]"
val res = str.drop(1).sliding(2, 4).toList
println(res) // List(ab, bc, cd, dx, 42)

val str2 = "[ab]"
val res2 = str2.drop(1).sliding(2, 4).toList
println(res2) // List(ab)

val str3 = ""
val res3 = str3.drop(1).sliding(2, 4).toList
println(res3) // List()
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try:

```
str.split("(\\]\\[)|(\\[)|(\\])").filterNot(_.isEmpty)
```

Mainly using groups `(][, ], [)` for delimiter and trimming the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=\[)([^]]+)(?=\])
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jY2gA9/1)

**Code:**

```
scala> val re = "(?<=\\[)([^]]+)(?=\\])".r
re: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?<=\[)([^]]+)(?=\])

scala> for(m <- re.findAllIn("[ab][bc][cd][dx][42]")) println(m)
ab
bc
cd
dx
42
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `][` is the delimiter between any two consecutive items, consider

```
str.drop(1).dropRight(1).split("\\]\\[")
```

delivers

```
Array("ab", "bc", "cd", "dx", "42")
```

**Update**

A tiny bit more general an approach, where we define `String` delimiters,

```
implicit class Spl(val str: String) extends AnyVal {
  def regSplit(leftDel: String, rightDel: String) = 
    str.stripPrefix(leftDel).stripSuffix(rightDel).split(rightDel+leftDel)
}
```

Thus

```
str.regSplit("\\[","\\]")
res: Array[String] = Array([ab, bc, cd, dx, 42])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

The easiest and most logical way is to match and not split.Just match and grab the captures or group 1.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/42

Comment: How would I implement the match in scala?